# Django split settings environment with environment variables

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I have a `common.py`, `dev.py`, and `prod.py` for my Django settings files. All files inherit from `common.py`. I want to keep my database passwords, database URL, etc stored as environment variables & out of my online repository.

I have researched environment variables on Stackoverflow, and the web but I am not sure if I have a clear understanding of it.

What exactly should I type in my bash shell or would something like `export SOMEAPP_DB_USER='someapp'`, `export SOMEAPP_DB_PASSWORD='1234'`, go in my `bash_profile`?

If the command is issued via the shell is it only good for the terminal session that I am in or is it permanently set whenever I invoke my applications virtual environment?

Should the settings file be setup as follows ?

```
DATABASE_USER = os.environ.get("SOMEAPP_DB_USER", ")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("SOMEAPP_DB_PASSWORD", ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An environment is associated with a process, and a copy inherited when the parent process forks.  You can have bash inject settings into an environment before running another command.

The following command will run `./manage runserver` with the existing bash environment, with the addition of two extra environment variables `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `MY_DB_PASSWORD`.

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.dev MY_DB_PASSWORD=foo ./manage.py runserver
```

As you suggested, you could then use the following Python code in your settings file to extract values from the environment.

```
import os
db_passwd = os.environ.get('MY_DB_PASSWORD', 'default-db-password')
```

You could put your passwords in `.profile`, but it's probably a bad idea since you then have sensitive information mixed with non-sensitive.  You'd then you have to protect the `.profile` file permissions, otherwise others will simply be able to read the file to obtain your passwords.

I think a better approach for settings management in this case is to have a separate file dedicated to sensitive settings such as passwords.  Have this file's permissions protected to be readable just by those users who need it, eg your web server.  You could then read this password file from your `settings.py` to obtain passwords.  The use of the Python [ConfigParser module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) may be useful here.

You could use an environment variable to specify where this file is located if wanted, or fall back to a default if none specified.

eg.
    DB_PASSWD_FILE=~/tmp/test_db_passwords.ini ./manage.py runserver

Then in `settings.py`

```
import os
db_passwd_file = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD_FILE', '/etc/myproject/db_passwords.ini')

# Instantiate a ConfigParser object here to read passwords from db_passwd_file.
```

This allows the default behaviour to look in the system protected file `/etc/myprojecdt/db_passwords.ini` unless the location has been overridden by the `DB_PASSWD_FILE` environment variable.

During development, you could set up `DB_PASSWD_FILE` to point to a sane location for development purposes in `.profile`.  The path that `DB_PASSWD_FILE` points to could be protected to be readable just by you using file system permissions.

Comment: Thank you. This was excellent in helping me understand what environment variables do and how they actually work.